# How to convert date value to oracle date value?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have a requirement where I need to convert a date value(14-08-2013) to (14-AUG-13). I have used the below query but its not working:

```
select *
from ind_holidays
where hol_date between to_date('11-08-2013', 'dd-mmm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND to_date('17-08-2013', 'dd-mmm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
ORDER by name
```

Comment: Why are people re-editing and _leaving/re-adding the stuff that should be fixed?_

Comment: Formatting is normally best done client-side, not server side, because the day you need to internationalize everything, if you have done it piecemail, it'll be a nightmare.

Comment: It's not clear from your question *why* you would want to convert your dates to `DD-MON-YY` format when you're just comparing them with (presumably) DATE columns in your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the time part in to_date format string is unnecessary.  change your query like this:

```
select *
from ind_holidays
where hol_date between to_date('11-08-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND to_date('17-08-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
ORDER by name
```

and use `mm` instead of `mmm` for month in 2 digits

Answer (score 2):

Oracle's `TO_DATE` function expects the format string to be an match for the input.

```
to_date('11-08-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

(**note**: `mm` for a 2-digit month number, not `mmm` - three-character months use `mon`) will convert a string into a date, which your query should be handling. The `hh24:mi:ss` part isn't necessary, as you don't have a time component in your string. Oracle 11g on my machine still handles it though.

But your question says

> I need to convert a date value(14-08-2013) to (14-AUG-13)

...which looks like is might be an output issue? A date column in the output, perhaps? The same formatting strings apply, for example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(hol_date, 'DD-MON-YY') FROM ...
```

Comment: Mike, `YYYY` shouldn't be `YY` since OP wants last two digits of year?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this;

```
to_date('11-08-2013', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

- [TO_DATE Format Masks](http://psoug.org/definition/TO_DATE.htm)

`D` - *Day of the month*

`MON` -     *Month in three characters, i.e. "Jan","Feb", "Apr*

`YY` - *Last two digits of the year.*